# Can a neural network with random connections still work correctly?

Tags: neural-network

Let's say we have a neural network with n layers where connections do not simply go from layer i to layer i+1, but can go from any layer i to any layer k such that k > i. For example; connections from layer 1 directly to layer 3, or layer 2 directly to layer n, etc...

Given an arbitrary training function and some chosen activation function for each layer, would such a neural network still work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is yes, but, as so often with neural networks, it depends on your problem.

The type of architecture you're describing in your question is called a "skip-layer" model. For a brief discussion of skip-layer connections, you might want to check these online resources:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56950/neural-network-with-skip-layer-connections

http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~bengioy/ift6266/H12/html.old/mlp_en.html

https://www.google.com/search?q=skip+layer+neural+network

Summary: skip layer connections can work, but how well they work depends heavily on your problem, and on how the rest of your network model is built and optimized.

Answer (score 2):

For a(any) NN what you get is a combination of chained activation functions.

As long as the weight of all connections give you the good classification result it shouldn't matter if you skip some layers.

And mathematically you can still use the chain rule to do the backpropagation, I imagine it is less clean compare to the layer by layer backpropagation.

The only problem I see is by skipping too many layers your model may not be complex enough to catch the relationship between the input and output, which is usually not a problem for NN.